# Why My Built-in Spring Classes Doesn't Have Docstring?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, I watched Spring tutorial on YouTube, and I notice that the speaker has docstring inside a built-in Spring class, in this case `SecurityContext` class.
[image: SecurityContext class with docstring]

Howver, when I open the same class on my IDE, I don't find any docstring:
[image: SecurityContext class on my IDE]

Is there any configuration I miss so in my IDE it doesn't show the docstring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using Intellij IDEA, in IntelliJ you'll see the `Download Sources` button at the top when you open the `.class` files. Clicking it will download the sources i.e. `.java` files that contain the docstrings.

For example:
[image]